# Windows 8(.1) Disable Metro Left Click Network Manager Popup?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Clicking on the Network tray icon, pops up a metro style strip from the right side.
This is not just annoying, it's also useless since you can't do anything with it.
Any way to get rid of this? I liked the windows 7 style of popup. :)

Thanks!

p.s, lost my old account so can't post the screen shot for metro style "manager", so here's the link: 
[image]

Comment: If you post on meta.superuser.com you can get help connecting your new account to your old account.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click on a network you are already connected to?  Right Click in this context would make the most sense.

Comment: I deleted the old gmail address, and I dont even remember the address... forgot having this on it :P

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Right-click Taskbar followed by clicking `Properties` in the context menu.
2. Then click the `Navigation` tab.
3. Now, under the Corner navigation section, simply uncheck `When I point to the upper-right corner, show the charms` option and hit `Ok`.

[image]

I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have charms disabled, this doesn't change the network manager's behavior.